# Unity not working. No panels nor file menus. (Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...)

Tags: unity, gnome

Pastebin file 
http://pastebin.com/UTeLDG3v

Thing is i get errors like these.

```
WARN  2014-06-17 15:59:45 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
```

Why cant it register objects?
Tried reinstalling and all the stuff but i can run unity from gnome or terminal for some time.
Tried rebooting multiple times.
Still doesn't work.
Still no panels nor file menus.
I am on the newest version of Ubuntu.
Also i had a problem earlier where I couldnt empty my Trash bin and I fixed that.
Still could i have delete some other files?